# Error: Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

Why does this error occur? I specified an identifier for the `TableViewCell` and classes for `TableViewCell` and `TableViewController`.

Also I tried to register my cell in `viewDidLoad` in `TableViewController`:

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

but in this case I got an error on the same line:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

**Code:**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //...
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell //ERROR HERE: Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

        return cell
    }
}
```

**TableViewController settings:**

[image]

**TableViewCell settings:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")` ? So use `TableViewCell` instead of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @koen in this case I got an error: `Thread 1: "*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"`

Comment: @koen Also I noticed a strange thing: I have a label in a cell declared in the storyboard, so I can't drag it from the storyboard into the `TableViewCell` code (a blue line appears but I'm not offered to create `IBOutlet`). If I try to drag the label to `TableViewController` `class`, then everything is fine, I can create `IBOutlet`. I'm new to UIKit so I don't understand, can it be so?

Comment: Follow @koen advice. Now the error you get is elsewhere, and not there. Could you find where it make it crash?

Comment: @Larme on the same line (`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell`)

Comment: What is the value of `indexPath` ?

Comment: @koen `[0, 0]` and `[0, 1]` (so it looks like an error after `[0 ,1]`)

Comment: @koen tried using `Dynamic Prototypes` instead of `Static Cells` in `Table View` and it worked. Apparently I do not quite understand the difference in using both